What kind of dash is used for (sentence/word) truncation?
Examples
Sometimes I see a sentence truncated. Consider the undermentioned:

Not Truncated

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

...versus:

Truncated

Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame—



Evidently, the 2nd quotation was prematurely truncated. The em-dash demonstrates this. However, it's not the sole available punctuation:
Possibilities

Period
. is utilized for shorter sentences, especially names. However, because it's more frequently utilized to demonstrate sentence cessation, it isn't ideal.
Consequently, I would prefer to utilize a dash, which appears to be the sole (punctuational) alternative:

Dashes

Hyphen-Minus (-)
This type of dash appears to serve any purpose. However, it's rather a fallback for when someone hasn't bothered to ascertain how they should better punctuate something.
However, considering that I utilize a standard ISO QWERTY UK keyboard layout on my desktop computer, this would be convenient.

En-dash (–)
It appears to be utilized solely to semantically mark date-time ranges, or as parenthesis when space between the clause and its punctuation would render it more readable than the undermentioned alternative (or ( and )).

Em-dash (—)
As aforeutilized in the example (I had to pick one, and it was most evidently different to the hyphen-minus due to its length). It's sole differentiating use case appears to be as an alternative form of parenthesis when ( and ) have been utilized too frequently.




Which is correct?
Rationale

Occasionally, dialogue (usually of a fictional character) is prematurely interrupted, and this must be indicated to prevent confusion.
Consider the recent interruption of D. Trump's speech, if an example isn't evident.

I hit a character limit when pasting something, and don't have much choice except to demonstrate this.
This usually occurs when filling a poorly designed form. It may appear superfluous. However, it's been assistive in the past, because the recipient is able to understand without me needing to redact a significant amount of information to communicate this.


(Lack of) Duplicates
This was originally marked as not merely related, but a duplicate, of Should there be a space after an em dash if the dash is used to cut off the end of a sentence and a new sentence begins afterwards?.
However, I don't consider it so, because that question refers to a concatenation of two sentences with relevant topics. Its top comment - Should there be a space after an em dash if the dash is used to cut off the end of a sentence and a new sentence begins afterwards? rightfully states:

Why are you using em-dashes here instead of ellipses…?

...which I agree with, for an em dash is nonsensical there when the ellipsis exists to more clearly distinguish the premature sentence break.
Consider the difference between HTML's <q> and <blockQuote> - whereas that question asks about inline punctuation, this one asks about block-level punctuation.

Sven Yargs' answer provides a level of support for using the dash rather than the ellipsis; the comment you cite has no supporting reference. // Tinfoil Hat essentially answers that the choice is a free one (although only giving a reference from one style guide, CMoS). The spaced en-dash is more commonly used in the UK than it is in the US, often where the American choice is for the unspaced em-dash. But the ellipsis would be more normal anyway n formal examples such as the Latin quote you give. The dash invokes an interruption or shift in focus rather than a tailing off.

You mean a space at the end of the line? With or without closing quotation marks? Can you give a specific example of the precise situation you are asking about, with all punctuation, line endings, paragraphs, etc, clearly shown? It's normal to put quoted speech in quotation marks in fiction (in English it's the default but not universal, the French are different); the exception is that if speech continues into the next paragraph there is no end quotation mark, but if you're interrupted I don't really see how that would apply. I also don't see how a block quote would be interrupted.

@StuartF, are you asking Edwin or I? I presume myself. Consequently, regarding "I also don't see how a block quote would be interrupted": the same way that an inline one would be. The distinction I intended to make in my postface was that the question which was previously marked as a duplicte of this one explicitly asked about concatenation after interruption, which is quite a distinct topic. I hope that answers your question(s).

This is between you and your style guide. According to The Chicago Manual of Style:

To show an interruption to quoted speech or dialogue, an em dash is
normally used (see also 6.93). As with question marks and exclamation
points, which take the place of commas and periods at the end of
quoted speech (see 6.133, 6.134), the dash alone signals the end of
the speech.
“Don’t inter—” The egg came out of nowhere, striking the teacher
on the forehead.
“Why do you always—” “Always what?”
“Did I ever tell you about the—” he began, but nobody was
listening.
. . . For faltering speech and incomplete thoughts, which are signaled by ellipses, see 12.43. For speakers interrupting themselves, see 12.44.
Source: The Chicago Manual of
Style—12.42: Interrupted
speech (login required)


Thank you. Though, note that I'm a mere person wanting to write well, so I've no authority enforcing a style guide. In that vein, do people generally choose a style guide to adhere to in their personal writing? If so, that might make a lot of choices easier.

For consistency and efficiency, every writer should adopt a style guide. How to choose ...

Thanks. I'll do so, then.
